# How to group Jmeter Results by Controller Name

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jmeter project in the following Structure.

```
Thread Group
|
|_ Simple Controller 01
     |__ Sampler 01
     |__ Sampler 02
|
|_ Simple Controller 02
     |_ Sampler 03
```

My requirement is to run my Jmeter Script in Non-GUI mode and generate a JTL or some other report which maintains the exact grouping of my project. How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way to do that is to start each of your Samplers with a number. So you would have `1_Sampler` instead of `Sampler 01`. JMeter should sort alphabetically by default.

I don't **like** this solution, but I couldn't find another one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using jp@gc Flexible file writer. this will resolve your problem.

details on https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin